# Tracking Undo and Redo Commands on External Keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, keyboard

I am working with an external keyboard, implementing UIKeyCommands for iOS. The commands are working fine, although Apple does not allow me to override the key command for undo and redo (Cmd-Z/Cmd-shift-z).

Therefore, I need to figure out what the iOS methods are that are being called on the first responder when these commands are pressed so that I can do stuff when they are called.

These methods are also the ones called when the undo and redo buttons are pressed by the keyboard on iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSUndoManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/) in iOS does send out notifications immediately before undo and redo happens.

Look at notifications like [`NSUndoManagerWillUndoChangeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/NSUndoManagerWillUndoChangeNotification), and then you can "do stuff" before undo gets performed.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. However, my current situation is that I have an undo and redo button, as well as an external keyboard. One part of why I would need this is so that I can update the undo and redo buttons' state when Cmd-Z is pressed.


Unfortunately, this notification occurs regardless of how the NSUndoManager was called and so I do not know if the user pressed Cmd-Z, or if the button was pressed. If the button was pressed, the button state was already handled.

Ultimately this could work but might end up doing the same work twice. Ideally I would be able to determine the method used

Comment: To clarify a little more, I am less concerned with when things are actually about to be undone and more about hooking in to the Cmd-Z and Cmd-Shift-Z keyboard commands, which unfortunately you cannot do with the keyCommands.